# How I can search in Mongo based on field that doesn't contain .dot operater?

Tags: mongodb-query

Below is the query that works for userName doesn't start with **T** character

```
db.users.find( { userName: { $not: /^T.*/ } } )
```

But I want to write a query for a date field which doesn't contain . dot operator ?

> "\"2015-06-09T04:42:54+00:00\"" ** - should be listed
>
> "\"2016-08-24T08:42:39.017+00:00\"" - should not be listed as it
>   contains '.'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Tried with $not and regex operation, but unable to fetch the results.

Comment: I don't know how i can use reserved operators like dot operator in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression matches all strings which do not contain a '.'

```
> db.users.find({date: {$regex: "^[^.]+$"}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you explain this regex ? Why there is need of +$ ?

Comment: @Megha the $ signifies the end of the regular expression.